# What is wrong with my configuration? AWS - IoT using MQTT

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot

I am following the developer guide for amazon web service IoT, but I have run into some beginner problems and I don't know what to do to solve them. I been sitting for two days. This is what has happened (I am using mac):

1st problem: 
In this guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html
I can see and edit my profile by calling "$ was configure" in the terminal. If I call "ls ~/.aws" I can see the config and the credentials folder. But if i call: "~/.aws/credentials" or "~/.aws/config", I get the following error: -bash: /Users/christopher/.aws/credentials: Permission denied. 
If i search in finder no file names aws is found.

2nd Problem: 
On the next page of the guide, at number 11. i can't get the dot go green cause I get an error when I press connect. The MQTT.fx tool says that it can't find the rootCA.pem file, in the Log. Like this:

```
2015-11-10 09:55:48,330  INFO --- ScriptsController              : Clear console.
2015-11-10 09:55:48,332  INFO --- MqttFX ClientModel             : MqttClient with ID fc47354d17e84b6c8507eb1accb61560 assigned.
2015-11-10 09:55:48,340 ERROR --- MqttFX ClientModel             : Error when connecting
java.io.FileNotFoundException: rootCA.pem (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at de.jensd.mqttfx.ssl.SSLFellow.loadX509CertificatePem(SSLFellow.java:173) ~[MQTT.fx-jfx.jar:?]
    at de.jensd.mqttfx.ssl.SSLFellow.createSSLSocketFactory(SSLFellow.java:51) ~[MQTT.fx-jfx.jar:?]
    at de.jensd.mqttfx.model.MqttFXClientModel.getMqttConnectOptions(MqttFXClientModel.java:713) ~[MQTT.fx-jfx.jar:?]
    at de.jensd.mqttfx.model.MqttFXClientModel.connect(MqttFXClientModel.java:420) ~[MQTT.fx-jfx.jar:?]
    at de.jensd.mqttfx.services.BrokerConnectService$1.call(BrokerConnectService.java:68) ~[MQTT.fx-jfx.jar:?]
    at de.jensd.mqttfx.services.BrokerConnectService$1.call(BrokerConnectService.java:65) ~[MQTT.fx-jfx.jar:?]
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at javafx.concurrent.Service.lambda$null$493(Service.java:725) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at javafx.concurrent.Service.lambda$executeTask$494(Service.java:724) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_60]
2015-11-10 09:55:48,563  INFO --- ScriptsController              : Clear console.
2015-11-10 09:55:48,563 ERROR --- BrokerConnectService           : FileNotFoundException: rootCA.pem (No such file or directory)
```

When i click the "..." button next to the certificate I Notice two things. 
1. The certificates here created in my user folder, not in the aws? config folder. 
2. No rootCA.pem certificate have been created.

I followed this tutorial to sign my own rootCA.pem certificate: http://datacenteroverlords.com/2012/03/01/creating-your-own-ssl-certificate-authority/

Then in the MQTT.fx tool I press the "..." buttons again next to each certificate to manually select each certificate. The path to each one is displayed, like this: /Users/christopher/cert.pem

When I try to connect again i get the following error in the MQTT.fx tool:

```
2015-11-09 17:00:30,634  INFO --- ScriptsController              : Clear console.
2015-11-09 17:00:30,635 ERROR --- BrokerConnectService           : NullPointerException: null
2015-11-09 17:43:17,544  INFO --- BrokerConnectorController      : onConnect
2015-11-09 17:43:17,592  INFO --- ScriptsController              : Clear console.
2015-11-09 17:43:17,595  INFO --- MqttFX ClientModel             : MqttClient with ID fc47354d17e84b6c8507eb1accb61560 assigned.
2015-11-09 17:43:17,661 ERROR --- MqttFX ClientModel             : Error when connecting
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.jensd.mqttfx.ssl.SSLFellow.loadPem(SSLFellow.java:221) ~[MQTT.fx-jfx.jar:?]
    at de.jensd.mqttfx.ssl.SSLFellow.loadPrivateKeyPem(SSLFellow.java:184) ~[MQTT.fx-jfx.jar:?]
    at de.jensd.mqttfx.ssl.SSLFellow.createSSLSocketFactory(SSLFellow.java:55) ~[MQTT.fx-jfx.jar:?]
    at de.jensd.mqttfx.model.MqttFXClientModel.getMqttConnectOptions(MqttFXClientModel.java:713) ~[MQTT.fx-jfx.jar:?]
    at de.jensd.mqttfx.model.MqttFXClientModel.connect(MqttFXClientModel.java:420) ~[MQTT.fx-jfx.jar:?]
    at de.jensd.mqttfx.services.BrokerConnectService$1.call(BrokerConnectService.java:68) ~[MQTT.fx-jfx.jar:?]
    at de.jensd.mqttfx.services.BrokerConnectService$1.call(BrokerConnectService.java:65) ~[MQTT.fx-jfx.jar:?]
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at javafx.concurrent.Service.lambda$null$493(Service.java:725) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at javafx.concurrent.Service.lambda$executeTask$494(Service.java:724) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_60]
2015-11-09 17:43:18,472  INFO --- ScriptsController              : Clear console.
2015-11-09 17:43:18,473 ERROR --- BrokerConnectService           : NullPointerException: null
```

I can see on the aws IoT site (the console?) that the certificate, the policy and the lightbulb are all connected just like in the tutorial. But the rest is a mystery. 
I would be so happy for all help I can get. Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve by signing your own root CA? The rootCA.pem file shoud be downloaded from [here](https://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/verisign/roots/VeriSign-Class%203-Public-Primary-Certification-Authority-G5.pem). 

And did you also use the "..." button to select the rootCA.pem file corrresponding to the root certificate?

Answer (score 1):

2. You have to sign your own CA when you use your own domain name. Location of the original root certificate can be found at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/verify-pub-sub.html

Comment: Thank You.
I made a copy of a another certificate and replaced its content of a link from symantec. It worked! 

Now MQTT.fx managed to connect and I can publish and subscribe messages in both the tool and in the terminal. It all seems to work, but for some reason the message wont add to the DynamoDB -database. 
In DynamoDB I made a table with  Hask Key "UserID" and Range Key "SensorTitle".
In IoT I made a (Dynamo action) rule which is connected to the Dynamo Db table, and has a Has Key Value of ${topic(2)} and a Range Key Value of ${timestamp()}.

The message is {\"topic\" : \"topic, World\"}

Answer (score 0):

The root CA certificate is not created for you, rather it is linked somewhere in the AWS IoT documentation and is the same for all.

See first parapgraph here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/verify-pub-sub.html

The is the root CA:
https://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/verisign/roots/VeriSign-Class%203-Public-Primary-Certification-Authority-G5.pem